# Modifying Response of Graphql before sent out

Tags: javascript, graphql, apollo-server

I am looking for a way to modify the response object of a graphql query or mutation before it gets sent out.

Basically in addition the the data object, I want to have extra fields like code and message.

At the moment I am solving this by adding the fields directly into my GQL schemas take this type definition for example:

```
type Query {
  myItems: myItemResponse
}

type myItemResponse {
  myItem: Item
  code: String!
  success: Boolean!
  message: String!
}
```

The response itself would be look like that:

```
{
   data: {
      myItems: {
         myItem: [ ... fancy Items ... ],
         message: 'successfully retrieved fancy Items',
         code: <CODE_FOR_SUCCESSFUL_QUERY>
      }
   }
}
```

I find that solution not nice because it overcomplicates things in my FrontEnd.

I would prefer a solution where message code and other Metadata are seperated from the actual data, so something like this:

```
{
   data: {
      myItems: [ ... fancy Items ... ],
   },
   message: 'successfully retrieved fancy Items',
   code: <CODE_FOR_SUCCESSFUL_QUERY>
}
```

With apollo-server I already tried the formatResponse object in the constructor:

```
const server = new ApolloServer({
   ...
   formatResponse({ data }) {
     return {
        data,
        test: 'Property to test if shown in the FrontEnd',
     }
   }
   ...
}
```

unfortunately that doesn't have the desired effect. Before I use express middlewares I want to ask if there is a possibility to do this via apollo-server out of the box or if I am maybe just missing something in the formatResponse function.

Comment: `formatResponse` is the correct way to go about adding these fields. Saying "doesn't have the desired effect" doesn't describe the issue you're having. Please specify what behavior you expected and what unexpected behavior you encountered.

Comment: well what I mean is even though I return { data, test } I only get data returned in the response the expected behaviour would be that the response contains { data, test }

Comment: GraphQL has [explicit support for errors](https://graphql.github.io/graphql-spec/June2018/#sec-Errors), on a per-field level even, and these errors can carry extension values like human-readable messages and machine-readable codes.  Apollo also has some [lightly-documented error handling](https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-server/blob/master/packages/apollo-server-errors/src/index.ts) that might meet your needs.

Comment: @Matt Check out this [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/pmjp5y7pxj). `formatResponse` works as expected. If your client on the front end **does not expose this information**, that's a separate issue. You can verify whether this is the case by opening the network tab and looking at the actual response received from the server.

Comment: If this is indeed what's happening, this question should probably be rewritten as something like "Why isn't [CLIENT] reading the custom properties I set in my response?"

Comment: its not what is happening the modified response never reaches the client. I can confirm that your sandbox is working exactly how I desire it. For some reason it is not for me which I just not understand because the console.log in the formatResponse is triggered showing up in the Node console Which makes it more confusing for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[from graphql.org:](http://spec.graphql.org/draft/#sec-Response-Format)
A response to a GraphQL operation must be a map.

If the operation encountered any errors, the response map must contain an entry with key errors. The value of this entry is described in the “Errors” section. If the operation completed without encountering any errors, this entry must not be present.

If the operation included execution, the response map must contain an entry with key data. The value of this entry is described in the “Data” section. If the operation failed before execution, due to a syntax error, missing information, or validation error, this entry must not be present.

The response map may also contain an entry with key extensions. This entry, if set, must have a map as its value. This entry is reserved for implementors to extend the protocol however they see fit, and hence there are no additional restrictions on its contents.

To ensure future changes to the protocol do not break existing servers and clients, **the top level response map must not contain any entries other than the three described above.**

Answer (score 0):

After doing a lot of research I found out that the only allowed top level properties in a graphql responses are data, errors, extensions. Here you can find the regarding Issue in GitHub

[GitHub Issue](https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-server/issues/2030)

for my purpose I will probably use the extensions field.

Answer (score 0):

#### Example data modifier

This function will concat ":OK" suffix on each string in the output object

```
// Data/output modifier - concat ":OK" after each string
function outputModifier(input: any): any {
    const inputType = typeof input;

    if (inputType === 'string') {
        return input + ':OK';
    } else if (Array.isArray(input)) {
        const inputLength = input.length;
        for (let i = 0; i < inputLength; i += 1) {
            input[i] = outputModifier(input[i]);
        }
    } else if (inputType === 'object') {
        for (const key in input) {
            if (input.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                input[key] = outputModifier(input[key]);
            }
        }
    }

    return input;
}
```

#### Solution 1 - Override GraphQL Resolvers

Long story short: you have 3 main types (Query, Mutation, and Subscription).
Each main type has fields with resolvers.
The resolvers are returning the output data.

So if you override the resolvers you will be able to modify the outputs.

##### Example transformer

```
import { GraphQLSchema } from 'graphql';

export const exampleTransformer = (schema: GraphQLSchema): GraphQLSchema => {
    // Collect all main types & override the resolvers
    [
        schema?.getQueryType()?.getFields(),
        schema?.getMutationType()?.getFields(),
        schema?.getSubscriptionType()?.getFields()
    ].forEach(fields => {
        // Resolvers override
        Object.values(fields ?? {}).forEach(field => {
            // Check is there any resolver at all
            if (typeof field.resolve !== 'function') {
                return;
            }

            // Save the original resolver
            const originalResolve = field.resolve;

            // Override the current resolver
            field.resolve = async (source, inputData, context, info) => {
                // Get the original output
                const outputData: any = await originalResolve.apply(originalResolve.prototype, [source, inputData, context, info]);

                // Modify and return the output
                return outputModifier(outputData);
            };
        });
    });

    return schema;
};
```

##### How to use it:

```
// Attach it to the GraphQLSchema > https://graphql.org/graphql-js/type/
let schema = makeExecutableSchema({...});
schema = exampleTransformer(schema);
const server = new ApolloServer({schema});
server.listen(serverConfig.port);
```

This solution will work on any GraphQL-JS service (apollo, express-graphql, graphql-tools, etc.).

Keep in min with this solution you will be able to manipulate the `inputData` too.

#### Solution 2 - Modify the response

This solution is more elegant, but is implemented after the implementation of the directives and scalar types and can not manipulate the input data.

The specific for the output object is that the data is `null-prototype` object (no instance methods like .hasOwnProperty(), .toString(), ...) and the errors are locked objects (readonly).
In the example I'm unlocking the error object... be careful with this and do not change the structure of the objects.

##### Example transformer

```
import { Translator } from '@helpers/translations';
import type { GraphQLResponse, GraphQLRequestContext } from 'apollo-server-types';
import type { GraphQLFormattedError } from 'graphql';

export const exampleResponseFormatter = () => (response: GraphQLResponse, requestContext: GraphQLRequestContext) => {
    // Parse locked error fields
    response?.errors?.forEach(error => {
        (error['message'] as GraphQLFormattedError['message']) = exampleTransformer(error['message']);
        (error['extensions'] as GraphQLFormattedError['extensions']) = exampleTransformer(error['extensions']);
    });

    // Parse response data
    response.data = exampleTransformer(response.data);

    // Response
    return response;
};
```

##### How to use it:

```
// Provide the schema to the ApolloServer constructor
const server = new ApolloServer({
    schema,
    formatResponse: exampleResponseFormatter()
});
```

#### Conclusion

I'm using both solutions in my projects. With the first you can control the input and the output based on specific access directives in the code or to validate the whole data flow (on any graphql type) .
And second to translate all the strings based on the context headers provided by the user without messing resolvers and the code with language variables.

Those examples are tested on TS 4+ and GraphQL 15 and 16